# Error to deserialize The InnerException message was 'ValueType 'System.Int32' cannot be null

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, entity-framework-migrations, k2

I am getting this error sporadically (it happened all the time about 2 hours ago, but now I am not getting the error) when bring up K2 forms (that uses K2 SmartObjects that calls WCF Service).
When I kept getting the error, it seems to be at different functions

http://tempuri.org/:GetAccountDetailsForWorkflowResult
   http://tempuri.org/:GetNewAccountFormInitializationDataResult

The InnerException message was always the same: 'ValueType 'System.Int32' cannot be null.'

```
Error: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the    message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:GetAccountDetailsForWorkflowResult. The InnerException message was 'ValueType 'System.Int32' cannot be null.'. Please see InnerException for more details.
```

Why did I get this error, and why now when I bring up the same workflows, I am not getting the error anymore ?
Also, we tested the same workflows and service on 2 testing environments, and it works with no error.

Could it be a problem with the network or the server ?

How do I find what variables gives the error The InnerException message was 'ValueType 'System.Int32' cannot be null.' ?

This is the class

```
  namespace Nuveen.Core.Entities
{
    public class SPONSOR
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int intRelationshipID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int intSponsorID { get; set; }
        public virtual SPONSOR Sponsor { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int intFirmID { get; set; }
        public virtual FIRM Firm { get; set; }
```

`public int? numFO { get; set; }`  --> I just added this column (to be added to the database)

```
[StringLength(250)]
public string vchSalesTeam { get; set; } --> I just added this column also
```

Comment: Your links redirect to bing , can your set corect link?

Comment: Hi, That's what shows up on error message. 
GetAccountDetailsForWorkflow and GetNewAccountFormInitializationData are 2 different functions in the WCF service.
We just deployed a new WCF service yesterday, and the only think that may be related with System.Int32 and null is: I added a new field in 1 of the class Sponsor.cs (Sponsor is a table in our database, we are using EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration). The new field is: public int? numFO { get; set; }
Could it be causing the error ? But, why the error doesn't happen all the time ?

Comment: Maybe problem is with deserialization data , your model property is not nullable, are you sure the problem exist and not exist with same data? Put code, your model class and deserialization method.

Comment: What did you mean by the problem is with deserialization data ?
>Are you sure the problem exist and not exist with the same data ?
Yes, we bring up the same screen earlier and got the error, and later no error, and later error.

Comment: Because I can't add too many characters to the comment, I added the class in my original post above (public class SPONSOR)

Comment: What if You add `[KnownType(typeof(DBNull))]` attribute to your class `SPONSOR`

Comment: Where shall I add that in the class ?
Do you know why the problem happens sometimes, but not other times ?
I would think if the problem is with the codes, it will happen all the time with the same data ? What do you think ? 
I am in such a loss.
I really appreciate you helping me.

Comment: I don't even know if that new column numFO that I just added cause the problem or not, but that column is an int? column .

I also just update the database data to set the value for numFO, so none of the row has NULL value for numFO. I am not sure if that will fix the problem or not ?

Comment: It looks like we found the problem, but we don't know 100% until the end of today. In one of our object AccountDetailsDto, FO used to be int, but I changed it for this deploy to be ?int.
public class AccountDetailsDto
{
    public int ?FO { get; set; }
Our WCF service is located in 2 servers (for load balancing). When it was deployed on Friday, the service in 1 of the server was refreshed, but the service in the other server wasn't refreshed.

Comment: So, yesterday night we refreshed the service in both servers. It makes sense why yesterday the problem was sporadic. When it worked, it must have hit the server that was refreshed on Friday. When it didn't work, it must have hit the server that wasn't refreshed. Also it makes sense why it worked on both of our test environments, because on test environments I always refreshed the service on both servers.